# How do I align th and td content of a table using Bootstrap 4?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Im having troubles with alignment of th and td content. I dont know what else to do, I´ve used all the possible classes in bootstrap 4 ex: text-center, center-block, align-items-center, justify-content-center and other but the table it looks the same. Please give me an idea to fix this issue or better help me to find the problem. Thanks in advance.[Table Employee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtnHR.png)

```
<div class="container-fluid" >
<div class="card border-1">
<div class="table-responsive  my-auto">
 <table id="tabla" class="table table-fixed table-striped table-condensed 
  text-nowrap mb-1">  
        <tr class="card-header bg-info text-center " style="color:white;">
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name Employees</th>
            <th>User Name</th>
            <th>Department</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Campaign</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="text-center"  >
            <td>'.$item['id_employee'].'</td>
            <td>'.$item['name_employee'].'</td>
            <td>'.$item['user_employee'].'</td>
            <td>'.$item['name_department'].'</td>
            <td>'.$item['name_position'].'</td>
            <td>'.$item['name_campaign'].'</td>

            <!--BUTTON DEL MODAL-->
            <td><a href="options.php?action=editEmployee&edit='.$item["id_employee"].'"> 
            <button type="button" style="border-radius:8px;" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm"> 
            <i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button></a></td>

             <td>
        <a href="options.php?action=employee&Del_Employee='.$item["id_employee"].'"> 
             <button style="border-radius:8px;" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" type="button">
             <i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></a></td> 
      </tr>
      </table>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: please add your HTML and CSS code here.Before they start downvoting your questions. Just trying to help

Comment: th, td { text-align: center;} this is the code for CSS. and is inside a function public function viewsEmployeesController(){
$id = $_SESSION["id"];
$respuesta  = Datos::viewsEmployeesModel($id);
  foreach ($respuesta as $row => $item) {
   # code...
  echo ' here goes the previous code....

Comment: (not *here in the comments*:) please edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the picture, it looks like you have multiple tables, something like:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>John Smith</td>
      <td>N/A</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Frank Peters</td>
      <td>Frank Peters has a much longer description than John</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Having multiple tables means that each table will resize it's columns, independent of the other ones.

What you want to do is put them in the same table:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>John Smith</td>
      <td>N/A</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Frank Peters</td>
      <td>Frank Peters has a much longer description than John</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hello Dave, in fact its only one but its inside of a CRUD procedure that extract the information from database

Comment: From the code you posted it doesn't look like it's only one table - where does the loop start?  I can see the `<table>` and the `</table>` in what you posted, so unless the loop starts inside of those tags and you removed it from the post for some reason, then you have more than one table.

Comment: public function viewsEmployeesController(){ $id = $_SESSION["id"]; $respuesta = Datos::viewsEmployeesModel($id); foreach ($respuesta as $row => $item) { # code... echo ' here goes the previous code. !!this is the code dave!!